# Euro Currency Input EditText Android

Tags: java, android, regex, currency

I want that my EditText behaves in this pattern:

- Starting Value is 0,00€ and when I put e.g. 123 it should output 123,00 €
- If I click on the comma it should set the cents value.

So far I used a TextWatcher

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        EditText editText = editTextWeakReference.get();
        if (editText == null) return;
        String s = editable.toString();
        if (s.isEmpty()) return;
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        String cleanString = s.replaceAll("[€,.]", "");
        BigDecimal parsed = new BigDecimal(cleanString).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).divide(new BigDecimal(100), BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
        String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY).format(parsed);
        editText.setText(formatted);
        editText.setSelection(formatted.length());
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
```

I got this snippet from another post and it works fine in $ but not with Euro!

If I put a number like 5 it will show 0,05 € that BUT if I input another number it crash and gives me this exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: de.hdmstuttgart.financemanager, PID: 32505
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "005 5"
```

Is there something wrong with my regex?

Comment: What is the value of `editable.toString()` before you use `replaceAll()` to clean it? It seems that the input is an invalid number.